# Bootstrap button with tooltip and modal, wrong padding in button group

Tags: html, css, button, bootstrap-5

I have a button-group of 2 buttons, each of them has a tooltip and a modal.
Bootstrap suggests to wrap buttons with spans to achieve the management of two "data-bs-toggle" attributes, and so I initially did that.

The functionality is fine, so the tooltip displays and the modal pops up when the button is clicked.

My issue is that doing so, the tooltip doesn't show if the cursor is in the padding of the button, but it only works if it's over the span (in my case the icon)

[image: In the green area, the tooltip isn't shown]

[image: In the padding area]

[[image: On the icon3]

I tried giving the span the "d-block w-100" class but it seems like it's not working.

Here's my code, using bootstrap 5:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group">
  <button class='btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#modalExport'>
                <span type="button" class="mgc-export-popup" tabindex="0"
                    data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Export">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-file-export fa-fw fa-lg"></i></span></button>
  <button class='btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#modalImport'>
                <span type="button" class="mgc-import-popup" tabindex="0"
                    data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Import">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-file-import fa-fw fa-lg"></i></span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: The buttons likely have padding. Can't you simply turn this around - and wrap the buttons into spans, instead of the button content into spans?

Comment: On a single button that works well, but when wrapped on a button-group, the button group style isn't applied anymore

Comment: `<span type="button"` - that's not a thing. Span does not have a type attribute.

Comment: Then you'll probably have to leave it as it currently is, and "move" the padding from the button to the span.

Comment: I was sure I tried that before but I guess I didn't... it works! :) I'll post the answer now

Answer (score 0):

As suggested  by CBroe, the solution was to set the **button's padding to 0** and **use padding on the span** element instead.
To make spacing work on span you also need to give it "display:block"

In my use case using bootstrap 5 the final solution was

- class `p-0` on the `button` elements
- classes `d-block p-2 px-3` on the `span` elements to keep the original proportions

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group">
  <button class='btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary p-0' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#modalExport'>
                <span class="mgc-export-popup d-block p-2 px-3" tabindex="0"
                    data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Export">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-file-export fa-fw fa-lg"></i></span></button>
  <button class='btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary p-0' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#modalImport'>
                <span class="mgc-import-popup d-block p-2 px-3" tabindex="0"
                    data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Import">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-file-import fa-fw fa-lg"></i></span></button>
</div>
```